# Running Quarkus app via gradle quarkusDev

Tags: kotlin, gradle, quarkus

I'm trying to start a `kolin Quarkus` app via `gradle` with the `quarkusDev` task.

What I've noticed is that it run `compileTestKotlin` task while starting up the app.
It takes about a minute for my system. Very inconvenient since I don't need the test code, I just want to run my app. I don't want to wait.

**Question:**
How do I remove this `compileTestKotlin` task from the `quarkuDev` tasks execution path ?
Is it possible ? What config do you need to change ?

EDIT: Here's my `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.allopen")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    jacoco
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg")
    id("io.quarkus")
    id("com.github.jk1.dependency-license-report")
    id("com.asarkar.gradle.build-time-tracker") version "3.0.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.google.com")
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Needed for Coveralls...
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31")
    }
}

group = "de.superchat"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

dependencies {
    // Quarkus
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-flyway")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-json")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-sentry")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler")
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:2.3.0.Final"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))

    // RestEasy
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-qute")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-mutiny")

    // SmallRye
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-jwt")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build")

    // Hibernate
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator")

    // PostgeSQL
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql")

    // AWS
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-sqs")
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.15.69")

    // Jackson
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    // Kotlinx
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.0-RC") // JVM dependency

    implementation("org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:4.5.5.Final")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")

    // Twilio
    implementation("com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.54.1")

    // Libphone
    implementation("com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.7")

    // Auth0
    implementation("com.auth0:auth0:1.19.0")
    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:3.10.3")

    // AWS
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.831")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:1.11.831")

    // Postmark
    implementation("com.wildbit.java:postmark:1.5.3") {
        exclude(group = "org.slf4j")
    }

    // HashIds
    implementation("org.hashids:hashids:1.0.3")

    // Google
    implementation("com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.9")
    implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.9")
    implementation("com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.15.0")
    implementation("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.31.2")
    implementation("com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.22.1")

    // Apache commons text
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9")

    // Pusher
    implementation("com.pusher:pusher-http-java:1.2.0")

    // Jsoup
    implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1")

    // Moustache Java
    implementation("com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:0.9.6")

    // Firebase
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1")

    // Three Ten Extra
    implementation("org.threeten:threeten-extra:1.5.0")

    // LaunchDarkly
    implementation("com.launchdarkly:launchdarkly-java-server-sdk:5.2.3")

    // Open CSV
    implementation("com.opencsv:opencsv:5.4")

    // CloudConvert
    implementation("com.cloudconvert:cloudconvert-java:1.0.7")

    // PDF Box
    implementation("org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.0-RC1")

    // Simple Java Mail
    implementation("org.simplejavamail:simple-java-mail:6.5.4")

    // Segment.io
    implementation("com.segment.analytics.java:analytics:3.1.3")

    // HiveMQ MQTT
    implementation("com.hivemq:hivemq-mqtt-client:1.2.1")

    // Tests
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:1.7.2.Final")
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5-mockito:1.7.2.Final")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:kotlin-extensions:4.3.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.15.1")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.15.1")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-db:2.0.0")

    // Mockito
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3")
    testImplementation("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.6.0")
    testImplementation("com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0")

    // Mockk
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.10.2")
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude(module = "logback-classic")
    }
}

val outputDir = file("$projectDir/build/classes/kotlin/main")

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    val instrument = tasks.named("instrument").get()
    val originalClasses = file("$outputDir-orig")

    if (hasTask(instrument)) {
        tasks.test.configure {
            classpath = layout.files(originalClasses, classpath.minus(outputDir))
        }
    }
}

// -- EXTENSIONS --
quarkus {
    setOutputDirectory("$projectDir/build/classes/kotlin/main")
    setWorkingDir("$projectDir") // Added to have a similar behavior as Spring Boot
}

noArg {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.ws.rs.Path")
    annotation("javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped")
    annotation("io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

// licenseReport {
//    outputDir = "$projectDir/build/licenses"
//    renderers = arrayOf<ReportRenderer>(InventoryHtmlReportRenderer("report.html", "Backend"))
//    filters = arrayOf<DependencyFilter>(LicenseBundleNormalizer())
// }

// --- TASK CONTAINER ---
tasks {
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
        options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
    }

    withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
            javaParameters = true
        }
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED")
        jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED")
    }

    quarkusDev {
        setSourceDir("$projectDir/src/main/kotlin")
    }

    create("instrument") {
        dependsOn(classes)
        finalizedBy(test)

        val jacocoAnt by configurations
        val originalClasses = file("$outputDir-orig")

        doLast {
            originalClasses.deleteRecursively()
            outputDir.renameTo(originalClasses)

            ant.withGroovyBuilder {
                "taskdef"("name" to "instrument", "classname" to "org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask", "classpath" to jacocoAnt.asPath)

                "instrument"("destDir" to outputDir) {
                    "fileset"("dir" to originalClasses)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    create("restore") {
        dependsOn("instrument")

        val originalClasses = file("$outputDir-orig")

        doLast {
            outputDir.deleteRecursively()
            originalClasses.renameTo(outputDir)
        }
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.isEnabled = true
        }
        dependsOn("instrument", test, "restore")
    }

    jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
        dependsOn("instrument", test, "restore")
    }
}

extensions.findByName("buildScan")?.withGroovyBuilder {
    setProperty("termsOfServiceUrl", "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service")
    setProperty("termsOfServiceAgree", "yes")
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Added build.gradle

Comment: Does adding `setDependsOn tasks.withType(KotlinCompile)` and `dependsOn tasks.withType(JavaCompile)` to `quarkusDev` work?

Comment: Should I just add this text "setDependsOn tasks.withType(KotlinCompile)" ?
Wont it just add the dependency ? Or does it disable it ?

Comment: setDependsOn should overwrite the task dependencies